# Capture values in TextView during Espresso tests

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso

I wanna capture all values in a TextView (that will be set periodically) and later see if the order of these values was correct. The test is in Espresso, is there any popular pattern/tool to do that?

Comment: Can you write some pseudocode in your question to explain exactly what you'd like to do in Espresso? That would probably help people to answer your question.

Comment: Finally, I created the mock Activity that captures everything for me and I'm checking in this Activity's state at the end of test.

Comment: If you found a solution, that's great. Feel free to answer your own question in more detail to help others who encounter this problem.

Comment: Thank you, usually, I'm doing that. However, I'm not sure if it's the best solution. Don't wanna spread bad practices.